# how to compile wxwidgets on aarch64 with neon disabled

Tags: android, linux, wxwidgets, arm64

I need to use a wxwidgets application on my rooted device running Ubuntu yakkety but when I compile with default settings and run it, this is what happens-

```
undefined symbol: wx_png_init_filter_functions_neon
```

What do I need to do to disable the neon specific code?

*Clarification*

This is not cross compiling. I am compiling wxwidgets on the device itself, i.e., on an aarch64 based system. also, ndk is not involved at all.

Here​are the args I ran configure.sh with-

`--disable-shared --enable-unicode --enable-compat28                   --with-libjpeg=builtin --with-libpng=builtin --with-libtiff=no --with-expat=no --with-zlib=builtin --disable-richtext --with-gtk=2 CFLAGS="-Os -fPIC" CXXFLAGS="-Os -fPIC"`

Comment: I would really like an answer to this question, please.

Comment: how did you configured the library?

Comment: edited the question.

Comment: can you try without "--with-libpng=builtin"?

Comment: it works! thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be a `libpng` problem; I fixed it by not using the `--with-libpng=builtin` compile time option, as suggested by Igor.